# Does the map $y \to |y|^a$ where a is an arbitrart constant satisfy Osgood condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, inequality

Is there a inequality satisfies$$\begin{align*}
|x^a-y^a|&\le F(|x-y|)
\end{align*}$$ where $F$ is just a function?  (or plus some other conditions, the inequality can hold)

I encounter this problem when trying to use the Osgood condition to prove the uniqueness of solutions for initial value problems. $$\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\frac{dy}{dx} =|y|^a \\ \\ y(0)=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$ My attempt was: $$\begin{align*}
||y_1|^a -|y_2|^a|&\le |y_1^a-y_2^a|\le F(|y_1-y_2|)
\end{align*}$$ But I was not able to find the function $F$ satisfies this. I get stuck with the power $a$ above $y_1, \ y_2$. Is there an inequality that can deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: We require $\left(y+k\right)^a-y^a\leq F(k)$, i.e. $\sup_y\left(y+k\right)^a-y^a\leq F(k)$.

In fact the solution is not unique for $a<1$ iirc (Tamarkine's nonuniqueness theorem or something)